# sqlalchemy: Insert html table into mysql db

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Im new to python (3) and would like to now the following:

I'm trying to collect data via pandas from a website and would like to store the results into a mysql database like:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql://python:"+'pw'+"@localhost/test?charset=utf8")

url = r'http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/devisen'
dfs = pd.read_html(url,header=0,index_col=0,encoding="UTF-8")
devisen = dfs[9] #Select the right table
devisen.to_sql(name='table_fx', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I'm receiving the following error:

....
   _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tBezeichnung\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t' in 'field list'") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO tbl_fx (`\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tBezeichnung\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t`, `\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tzum Vortag\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t`, `\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tLetzter Stand\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t`, `\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTageshoch\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t`, `\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTagestief\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t`, `\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t52-Wochenhoch\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t`, `\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t52-Wochentief\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t`, `\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDatum\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t`, `\nAktionen\t\t\t\t`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: (('VAE Dirham', '-0,5421%', 45321.0, 45512.0, 45306.0, 46080.0, 38550.0, '20.02.2018 14:29:00', None), ('Armenischer Dram', '-0,0403%', 5965339.0, 5970149.0, 5961011.0, 6043443.0, 5108265.0, '20.02.2018 01:12:00', None), ....

How can sqlalchemy INSERT respective data into table_fx? Problem is the header with the multiple \n and \t.

The mysql table hase the following structur:

(
   `name`            varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `bezeichnung`     varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `diff_vortag`     varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `last`            double DEFAULT NULL,
   `day_high`        double DEFAULT NULL,
   `day_low`         double DEFAULT NULL,
   `52_week_high`    double DEFAULT NULL,
   `52_week_low`     double DEFAULT NULL,
   `date_time`       varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `unnamed`         varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
)

Any help is higly welcome.

Thank you very much in advance

Andreas

Comment: your dataframe columns seem to contain many tabs in front of and after their real names; thus not matching the db columns

Comment: the problem isn't in the data, but the column name.  Mysql limits to 64 characters for column names.  You need to cleans your data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. Any idea how to clean the header and replace all \t and \n ? Sorry, I'm still learning. Thank you very much in advance - Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.  If you convert to a dataframe you can rename columns first.  The "dfs" entity you were creating was actually a list of dataframe entities.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql://python:"+'pw'+"@localhost/test?charset=utf8")

url = r'http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/devisen'
dfs = pd.read_html(url,header=0,index_col=0,encoding="UTF-8")

devisen = dfs[9].dropna(axis=0, thresh=4) # Select right table and make a DF

devisen.columns = devisen.columns.str.strip() # Strip extraneous characters

devisen.to_sql(name='table_fx', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: Great! That is what I'm looking for. Thank you very much for all your help.